# Multiline code replication with the C preprocessor

Tags: c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I want to replicate some code snippets using the C preprocessor. I know how to handle multi-line macros, but I am facing two difficulties:

1. I didn't find a way to embed comments in the macro,
2. The generated output doesn't have newlines.

E.g. here is what I would like to be able to do

```
#define Snippet \
// This is my snippet \
a= b + c;
```

(sort of).

Desired generated output:

```
// This is my snippet
a= b + c;
```

Do you have solutions for 1. and 2. ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "generated output" you show, is that the *actual* or *expected* output? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and both the actual and expected "generated output".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Expected. The macro definition, as written, cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the macro as you show it is because of how the compilation process works.

If you look at e.g. [this C translation phase reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) you will see that line-continuation happens in phase 2, then comments are replaced by space in phase 3, and finally preprocessing happens in phase 4.

That is, after phase 2 what you have is

```
#define Snippet // This is my snippet a= b+c;
```

Then after replacing comments in phase 3 the macro definition becomes empty.

The solution for comments is to use block comments using `/*` and `*/`.

There is no solution for the line-continuation problem, as that's how it must work.

Comment: Block comments do not work, they are swallowed by the preprocessor (thought I activate the Keep Comments option).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why do you want to keep comments in the expanded macro? Comments won't be in the compiled executable anyway, and as per the specification *must* be removed in phase 3. What is the *real* problem you try to solve?

Comment: I want readable source code generated by assembling snippets, compilation comes later.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I have solved as follows:

1. The following macro allows to embed C++-style comments:

   ```
   #define Comment(Text) #/#/ Text
   ```
2. I am adding a reserved character before the end of every line. After macro expansion, I turn it to a newline with a find/replace macro.

   ```
   #define Snippet \
   Comment(This is my snippet)@\
   a= b + c;
   ```

expands as

```
// This is my snippet@a= b + c;
```

and after substitution

```
// This is my snippet
a= b + c;
```

I am still looking for a way to have a symbol that would expand as a newline, though the current solution is already manageable.

Comment: `#/#/` is not legal C because the stringify operator only works with macro arguments. If you meant to stringify, you could have written it as `"/" "/"` but that doesn't seem consistent with your output. Perhaps you intended to try to concatenate the two slashes using `/##/`? But that's not legal C either because `//` is not a token.

Comment: @rici: what matters to me is that it works with my compiler, and it does, I don't know why.

Comment: in that case, consider adding the tag for your compiler to the question so that we don't think you're looking for a general solution.